# React Redux : Attempted import error always shown even if exported

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react app, with the following structure

```
├── App.jsx
├── actions
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── post_actions.js
│   └── types.js
├── components
│   ├── PostBox.jsx
│   ├── PostsList.jsx
│   ├── index.js
│   └── styles
├── index.jsx
├── pages
│   ├── Read.jsx
│   └── index.js
├── reducers
│   ├── post_reducer.js
│   └── index.js
├── serviceWorker.js
└── store
    └── index.js
```

Whenever I create a new ActionCreator, and attempt to use it, I always face the error :

```
Attempted import error: 'ACTION_CREATOR_NAME' is not exported from '../actions'.
```

even-thought I've **already exported** it. **This error disappear** as soon as I restart the react app, and the app works normally. Only appears whenever I create new action creator.

**post_actions.js snippet:**

```
import {
  FETCHING_POSTS_FAILED,
  FETCHING_POSTS_SUCCESS,
  FEATCHING_POSTS,
} from './types';

import { apiFetchPosts } from '../api/post';

export const getPosts = page => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: FEATCHING_POSTS });
    try {
      const { data } = await apiFetchPosts(page);
      dispatch(success(data));
    } catch (e) {
      const {
        response: { data }
      } = e;
      dispatch(error(data.error));
    }
  };
};
```

**my actions/index.js looks like the following:**

```
export * from './post_actions';
....
```

**Component Snippet:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getPosts } from '../actions';

class PostComponent extends Component {
....
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ posts} )=> {
...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(PostComponent)
```

This error is driving me crazy, I have no idea why its showing up, and after restarting it disappear. Anyone is having the same/similar issue ?

React version: 16.6
Redux Version: 4.0

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the file? Does a reload of the page, not a full restart, solve the issue as well?

Comment: Yeah I am sure I am saving the file, and I've reload the webpage as well but its not solved. Only restart works.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide a minimal working example for me to test?

Comment: Can you show how are you calling the action creator from your component?

Comment: @NikxDa It will take some time to provide a working example, the project is not on a public git repo.

Comment: @kumarmo2 , like this :
componentWillMount() {
const { getPosts } = this.props;
getPosts();
}

Comment: @DavidH but how is getPost, which is your ActionCreator, gettting passed to your component? are you using ``react`` and ``react-redux`` packages for it?

Comment: @kumarmo2 yes for sure i am using react-redux as you can see the "connect".  Note the second argument, that is how I pass the action creator to the component.  However, I do not think that is the issue, other-wise the code won't compile normally after i restart the react app and the actions get dispatched!! right ?